# error when using add-migration with edmfunction

Tags: c#, asp.net, ef-code-first, mapping

I'm using a edm function :

```
[DbFunction("dbo", "RemoveDiacritics")]
public static string RemoveDiacritics(string param)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls are not supported.");
}
```

I added this on the ApplicationDBContextClass :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    //Register a convention so we can load our function
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new RemoveDiacriticsFunctionConvention());
}
```

Since I'm using code first, I creaded the class for mapping :

```
public class RemoveDiacriticsFunctionConvention : IStoreModelConvention<EntityContainer>
{
    public void Apply(EntityContainer item, DbModel model)
    {
        //Delare your parameters name, edm type and mode (You can ignore this if you use a parameter-less function)
        List<FunctionParameter> Parameters = new List<FunctionParameter>();
        Parameters.Add(FunctionParameter.Create("StringValue", GetStorePrimitiveType(model, PrimitiveTypeKind.String), ParameterMode.In));

        //Same thing goes for the return type(s) (Why is it a list? Perhaps you can return tables? I haven't tested however since it is no use to me)
        List<FunctionParameter> ReturnParameters = new List<FunctionParameter>();
        ReturnParameters.Add(FunctionParameter.Create("ReturnValue", GetStorePrimitiveType(model, PrimitiveTypeKind.String), ParameterMode.ReturnValue));

        //Create the payload and fill the required information alone with the parameter lists we declared
        EdmFunctionPayload payload = new EdmFunctionPayload();
        payload.IsComposable = true;
        payload.Schema = "dbo";
        payload.StoreFunctionName = "RemoveDiacritics";
        payload.ReturnParameters = ReturnParameters;
        payload.Parameters = Parameters;

        //Create the function with it's payload
        EdmFunction function = EdmFunction.Create("RemoveDiacritics", "dbo", DataSpace.SSpace, payload, new MetadataProperty[] { });

        //Add it to the model
        model.StoreModel.AddItem(function);
        model.Compile();
    }

    //Little helper method to get the primitive type based on the database provider
    private EdmType GetStorePrimitiveType(DbModel model, PrimitiveTypeKind typeKind)
    {
        return model
            .ProviderManifest
            .GetStoreType(TypeUsage.CreateDefaultTypeUsage(PrimitiveType.GetEdmPrimitiveType(typeKind)))
            .EdmType;
    }

}
```

It works fine but the add-migration fails !

When I add a migration, I got this error :

> ```
> add-migration test -verbose
> Using StartUp project 'xxx'.
> Using NuGet project 'xxx'.
> ```
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.XDocumentExtensions.GetStorageMappingItemCollection(XDocument
>   model, DbProviderInfo& providerInfo)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument
>   sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Lazy`1
>   modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator
>   migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String
>   targetModelVersion)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Scaffold(String migrationName, String namespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder.Scaffold(String
>   migrationName, Boolean ignoreChanges)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Scaffold(MigrationScaffolder
>   scaffolder)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.RunCore()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
>       Sequence contains no elements

The error comes from this line :

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new RemoveDiacriticsFunctionConvention());
```

So far, I tried to add [nomapped] attribute on RemoveDiacriticsFunctionConvention class and :

```
modelBuilder.Ignore<RemoveDiacriticsFunctionConvention>();
```

But it still give me the same error !